# All gms libraries must use exact same version with places and maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places

I was using play-service-maps-8.1.0 version for my android google map app. Then i try to add new google place service 1.0.0 . Now it gives me all gms libraries must be exact same version error. I cant find any maps service in google's new service referances.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.1'
```

none of  them work with

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
```

How can i work with place and maps services in same app?

My all gradle dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Could you please add **all** the `dependencies` from the `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [places:1.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.libraries.places/places/1.1.0): it pulls in `play-services-maps:16.0.0` by itself -

and [places:1.1.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.libraries.places/places/1.0.0) does the same with `play-services-maps:16.1.0`.

---

You need to add this to the root project's `buildscript` `dependencies`:

```
classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0"
```

and these would be the module's Java `dependencies`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3"
    implementation ("com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"

    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2"
}

apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

For Places, without any Firebase dependencies or Play Services plugin, you'd still need to add at least add these two `string` resources (the project nevertheless needs to be setup on [Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com/), in order to obtain the required `google_services.json`, which contains the values to be substituted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <! -- Present in all applications -->
    <string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">YOUR_GOOGLE_APP_ID</string>

    <! -- Present in applications with the appropriate services configured -->
    <string name="google_api_key" translatable="false">YOUR_MAPS_API_KEY</string>

</resources>
```

see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin).

Comment: should i edit my previous code to new version of services and delete the gms implementation?

Comment: still get the same error. when i try to use route map, it says update play services but places works. when i delete the places, map works..

Comment: @comeonalready `places:1.1.0` even pulls in `play-services-base:16.1.0` (there is nothing to update) ...but you still need to apply the plugin & add the `google_services.json` to the project.

Comment: apply plugin google-services need google_services.json but im not using firebase.  i just cant do it with these instructions. none of the ways are work for me.

Comment: i know you are right. you solve the problem but i dont know what is wrong now it just not working :) . i accept your answer because it is the information the question needs. sorry if i do something wrong :)

Comment: @comeonalready I think you would still need to setup the project on Firebase, in order to obtain the `google_services.json`... where you can extract these two values from. without adding the `google_app_id` it cannot access `places`.